Analytical gradient of Softmax entropy loss does not match the numerical gradient
I'm trying to implement the gradient of the softmax entropy loss in Python. However, I can see that the analytical gradient does not match the numeric gradient. Here is my Python code:
import numpy as np

def softmax(z):
  expp = np.exp(z)
  
  return np.divide(expp, np.sum(expp))

def cost(z, y):
  s = softmax(z)
  
  return -np.sum(y * np.log(s)) / len(y)

def costprime(z, y):
  prime = []

  for i in range(len(z)):
    values = z.copy()

    values[i] += 1.0e-10

    prime.append((cost(values, y) - cost(z, y)) / 1.0e-10)

  return prime


z = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 0.3, -1.7])
y_expected = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0])

s = softmax(z)

cost_gradient = s - y_expected
numerical_derivative = costprime(z, y_expected)

print(cost_gradient)
print(numerical_derivative)

The result is:
[0.22151804  0.66547696 -0.90046553  0.01347053]

[0.05538014491435206, 0.16636914068612896, -0.2251154818111445, 0.0033673064336881]

They look very different. However, when I try to change the values of z to see their effect on the cost, I found out that numerical derivative is more accurate than the analytical derivative (cost_gradient)

You need to subtract the max from the rest of z in order to get numerical stability
expp = np.exp(z - np.max(z))
return expp / np.sum(expp)

Because the softmax function uses exponetials you can get values to overflow the capacity of the float representation.
By subtracting the max in the array, you remove this problem, while keeping the relative To avoid these issues, we can subtract the maximum value of the vector z from all elements before applying the exponential function. This trick ensures that all input values are shifted towards zero, preventing overflow while maintaining the correct relative differences between scores.

Yes, you're right. But that is not my major problem, which is the mismatch between the analytical derivative and numerical derivative! Do you have any clue about this issue?

Numerical gradients should be calculated using a central difference method instead of a forward difference method for better accuracy. Additionally, the way you're calculating the numerical gradient does not consider the vectorized form of softmax and cross-entropy loss, which might lead to further discrepancies.
